# Does "all day" refer just 1 day or every day?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

If we say *He played all day yesterday* or *He will play all day tomorrow*, it refers just 1 day.

Suppose, a boy plays all the time day by day and doesn't go to school.

**Do we have to say:?**

-*He plays all day every day*

or just

-*He plays all day*

Comment: Do we have to say **:?** - don't do this.

Comment: If it's clear from the context that you are talking about a habitual activity, you don't need to add _every day_.

Answer (score -1):

Saying "He plays all day every day" is needed: "all day" to show the length of time this goes on in a day, "every day" to show this is continual.

Comment: Not necessarily. "What X does all day" refers to their regular daily routine, not just one day. We sometimes add _every day_ just for emphasis.